# Android Sygic Embedded SDK doesn't show a map

Tags: android, module, sygic-mobile-sdk

I tried to integrate Sygic Embedded SDK in my Android App and I follow all steps from tutorial https://www.sygic.com/developers/professional-navigation-sdk/android/getting-started/embedded-integration-using-android-studio

I have correct ABI, in logcat are printed logs about **successful service connected** and initializations but **I don't see any map** as in the tutorial (see picture). The behavior of the module in my application is as follows:

1. Sygic loading
2. No maps found
3. No items available for purchase

Only one possible action is a **Quit** button which close the application. When I try to call method on ApiNavigation:

```
ApiNavigation.navigateToAddress("London", false, 0, 0)
```

logcat will print:

```
com.sygic.sdk.api.exception.NavigationException: Navigation not running.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Application id was not activated by the Sygic. That's why maps didn't download automatically.